# Enter filenames into attribute table

Tags: arcpy

I have an empty field in every shapefile called "District" and I want to pull the filenames from each of those files into that "District" field.

Here is my code so far:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = "TRUE"
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\d2000"
worksp = arcpy.env.workspace
files = arcpy.ListFiles("*.shp")
for shapefile in files:  
    arcpy.AddField_management(shapefile, "District", "TEXT")
```

Comment: If one of your shapefiles has 12,345 features then it sounds like you want the name of that shapefile to appear in your added field 12,345 times. To do that use the CalculateField tool.

Comment: Do you need a list of all the shapefile basenames in each row, or just the basename for the shapefile you are writing to?

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you are trying to do:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = "TRUE"
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\d2000"
worksp = arcpy.env.workspace
files = arcpy.ListFiles("*.shp")
for shapefile in files:
    arcpy.AddField_management(shapefile, "District", "TEXT")
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shapefile, ["District"]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[0] = shapefile
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Looks like the file path needs to be fixed e.g. `r"C:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\d2000"`